# Return type specification for wrapped method (TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, typescript, bcrypt

I'm trying to use the bcrypt module for Node with TypeScript's await / async options. The `compare` code is fairly simple:

```
    let compare = util.asyncWrap( bcrypt.compare );
    let result = await compare( password, stored );
    return result;
```

When I run that through the TypeScript compiler it says:

> error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Okay, fair enough it doesn't know that the resolved value from `compare` will be a boolean. The question is, how do I tell it that? Simply adding `:boolean` to the `result` object just moves the error.

This is my `asyncWrap` function:

```
export default function asyncWrap( fn ) {
    return function (...args) {
        return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {
            // Assume the callback handler goes at the end of the arguments
            args.push( function( err, val ) {
                // Assume that err is the first argument and value is the second
                if ( err ) {
                    reject( err );
                }
                else {
                    resolve( val );
                }
            } );

            fn.apply( fn, args );
        } );
    }
}
```

I should note that I am aware that I could use a promified version of bcrypt from npm, however, I'm just starting out with TypeScript and would like to understand how this is meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code do you specify that the return value of the operation is a boolean so the compiler can't infer that.

This should probably do the trick:

```
return new Promise<boolean>(function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the `asyncWrap` function can be used to wrap other functions that might return other types such as strings or objects. Without duplicating code I don't know how to go about telling it that for this specific case it should be a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Nitzan said, you can[use Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to do this:

```
util.asyncWrap<boolean>( bcrypt.compare );
```

And `asyncWrap` becomes:

```
export default function asyncWrap<T>( fn: Function ): Function {
    return function (...args): Promise<T> {
        return new Promise<T>( function ( resolve: Function, reject: Function ) {
            // Assume the callback handler goes at the end of the arguments
            args.push( function( err: Object, val: any ) {
                // Assume that err is the first argument and value is the second
                if ( err ) {
                    reject( err );
                }
                else {
                    resolve( val );
                }
            } );

            fn.apply( fn, args );
        } );
    };
}
```